# Pass a generic parameter through constructor

Tags: c#, .net, object, generics, parameters

I have two classes, **Companies** and **Contacts**, I need to pass an instance of one of those classes through a Constructor of a form.

```
    private Address _address;
    private Object _genericObject;

        public frmAddressAddModify(Address address = null, Object genericObject = null)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (address != null)
            {
                _address = address; 
            }

            if (genericObject != null)
            {
                _genericObject = genericObject;
            }

        }
```

But, I need to be able to use the properties and methods of the *genericObject* which could be a Company or a Contact, depending on what I'm passing.

By the way, the property I am using, is in Companies and Contacts under the same name (Address).

Comment: This looks like a classic usecase for interfaces. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface

Comment: If Company and Contact - are childs of genericObject, then treat those instances as genericObject class.

Comment: What's the type of `frmAddressAddModify` itself? Is it a `Form`? Otherwise, you could make it a generic type itself and reap all benefits.

Comment: There is no *generics* in the question... Are you looking for generics-based solution?

Comment: You are using the word "generic" in an ambiguous way. If all you mean is "an object of unknown type", then you can use the common base type that the `Company` and `Contract` types have in common as the parameter type. If you actually mean you want a generic method, then you have to give the method a generic type parameter, make the parameter that type, and constrain the type to (again) the common base type. If the two types don't share a common base type, then you'd have to cast explicitly in the method. In any case, the duplicates as well as many other identical questions show how.

Answer (score 2):

Polymorphism 101:

Have both classes implement an interface, and pass an instance of that into your class.

```
interface IHaveAddress // Please find a better name for this
{
    Address Address {get;}
}

class Companies : IHaveAddress
{
    public Address Address {get;} 
    // other staff goes here
}

class Contacts: IHaveAddress
{
    public Address Address {get;} 
    // other staff goes here
}
```

and in the form's constructor:

```
public frmAddressAddModify(IHaveAddress haveAddress)
{
// code here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a Generic Constructor in c#, I think this is what your aiming for. Why this object can be a Company or a Contact ? There is a connection between them right ? Maybe they can both implement the same interface. And you injected that interface. This is a workaround.

Comment: That's not entirely accurate - this is valid c#: `class X<T> { public X(T value) => Value = value; public T Value {get;} }`

Comment: Ah, you are right. Cool stuff :)